# dmesg Output - Mode Sense - Bytes Explanation

Tags: linux, scsi

Run `dmesg` and grep on `[sda] Mode Sense:` to return a row such as this:

```
[sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
```

What do the 4 bytes of data represent `00 3a 00 00`?

Its likely the answer is contained in a subsequent row of output such as:

```
[sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

... but I would like to know how to map the data to the descriptions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the first four bytes in the buffer returned from a mode sense command (see drivers/scsi/sd.c, sd_mode_sense()). The meaning can be gleaned by looking at drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c, scsi_mode_sense()): this routine returns a structure called "data" which, according to a comment, abstracts the mode header data; the first two bytes in the buffer (00 and 3a) are the high order/low order bytes of the length of "data" minus 2, the third byte (00) is the medium_type, and the fourth byte is device-specific:

```
        data->length = buffer[0]*256 + buffer[1] + 2;
        data->medium_type = buffer[2];
        data->device_specific = buffer[3];
```

So data->length is 0*256 + 0x3a + 2 = 60, the medium_type is 0 and who knows what the fourth byte means... (BTW, the `printk` that prints that Mode Sense: line is labeled `KERN_DEBUG` so it's really not meant for regular consumption).

You can use `sg_modes` from the `sg3_utils` package to examine things like this without having to go to extreme lengths to translate them:

```
 # sg_modes -a /dev/sg0
    ATA       SAMSUNG MZ7LN512  4L0Q   peripheral_type: disk [0x0]
Mode parameter header from MODE SENSE(10):
  Mode data length=60, medium type=0x00, WP=0, DpoFua=0, longlba=0
  Block descriptor length=8
> Direct access device block descriptors:
   Density code=0x0
 00     00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00

>> Read-Write error recovery, page_control: current
 00     01 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
>> Caching, page_control: current
 00     08 12 04 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 10     00 00 00 00
>> Control, page_control: current
 00     0a 0a 02 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff 00 1e
```

The other line you mention:

```
Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

is produced by the routine `sd_read_cache_type` in `drivers/scsi/sd.c`. It uses a couple of different sources for that information: the write and read cache information is obtained by looking at a specific byte of the modepage==8 buffer; the DPO/FUA information is obtained from the abovementioned "data" structure (although it does not necessarily contain the same data: the modepages used in the two calls may be different).

AFAICT, the information on this line and the information on the debugging line above are *not* directly related.

Comment: sd_mode_sense() in line two of your answer should be scsi_mode_sense()

Comment: Maybe, but it makes very little difference, if any: the message itself is printed by `sd_read_write_protect_flag()` which calls `sd_mode_sense()`. But this is a very short inline function that just calls `scsi_mode_sense()` and returns the result.

Comment: I only mentioned it so that the answer could be edited so as not to confuse others who reference it - many thanks for your time and thorough answer